# How to Create an Automatic Partial Mirror of Debian Packaging System?

Tags: debian, mirror

I have several machines at home running Debian Linux, and I've been wanting to make a partial mirror of the packaging system. I had considered making a full mirror, but I don't use most of the packages. However, most partial mirror solutions I've found require you to manually put packages a config file. Is there a way to have a partial mirror such that my local server downloads/updates packages when I install them on the client?

Also, maybe support for Ubuntu as well (I have a few Ubuntu VMs).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to do, but I understand not wanting to make a full mirror of Debian.  Of course, they define a full mirror as all the architectures, all the releases.

A smaller subset but still bigger than you want is to use `apt-mirror` - this way you can tone it down to a single release and architecture if you want.  https://apt-mirror.github.io/

What you probably DO want though is to cache any package the first time you download it and have it available for all machines on your network.  You can do this by putting a proxy in between your clients and the mirror servers, and there is a (well, a few but latest is) proxy/webserver combo all in one `apt-cacher-ng` that you can point your local Debian/Ubuntu/Mint/etc machines at. http://xmodulo.com/apt-caching-server-ubuntu-debian.html

Comment: My experiences with `apt-mirror` have not been good. Of the various [open issues](https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues), I've been bitten hard by [#49](https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/49) and discovered [#90](https://github.com/apt-mirror/apt-mirror/issues/90).

Comment: @rubicks - it works for me.  that said, i'm open to new options as well...

Comment: after my coworkers and I failed to get apt-mirror working, we tried [debmirror](https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/debmirror); it's been better behaved. We also like [aptly](https://www.aptly.info/) for repositories --- we don't (yet) use it to maintain mirrors.

Comment: Problem with using aptly for mirrors is it wants to re-sign repositories. You need to trust the gpg keys of the mirror.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but I've done something similar. Not entirely automatic, but involves typing only a few commands.

First get the list of what's in use (assuming all machines have the same arch):

```
$ apt list --installed > install.list
```

Then translate it into apt understandable format:

```
$ sed -r  's/ \[.*?\]//g' install.list | sed -r 's/(^.*?)\/.*?[ ](.*?)[ ](.*?)$/\1:\3=\2/g' > install.list.to.dl
```

Then download the current packages versions:

```
$ xargs apt download < install.list.to.dl
```

This will download all debs that were currently installed to the current directory.

You would need to create a Packages.gz file in order to add this folder as a source for apt. E.g.

```
$ cd ~/deb_server/debs/
$ dpkg-scanpackages -m . /dev/null | gzip -9c >  Packages.gz
```

EDIT: path for dpkg-scanpackages must be relative, otherwise this will break the download process later

(-m allows you to have multiple versions, if you want the most recent version, remove the -m)

Now you have to bring up a file server for example apache2 and configure it to index files.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-debserver.conf
```

Containing:

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www
   <Directory /var/www/>
     Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
     Require all granted
   </Directory>
```

And finally you need to symlink the deb folder to /var/www. (Or configure the server to the current deb download location) e.g.

```
$ ln -s ~/deb_server/debs/ /var/www/repo
```

The last bit is to add the server machine as the only source for apt updates on each target machine.

```
$ deb [trusted=yes] http://deb_server_ip/repo /
```

If you want to update the packages, you need to re-run apt download of the list, but without the version.

```
$ sed -r  's/ \[.*?\]//g' install.list | sed -r 's/(^.*?)\/.*?[ ](.*?)[ ](.*?)$/\1:\3/g' > install.list.for.update

$ apt update && xargs apt download < install.list.for.update
```

and update the Packages.gz.

I'm not sure this is the best way, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to control packages and dependencies from apt repositories, to be able to deploy the exact same content on multiple machines. I think it's a similar situation to yours where you want to keep a client and server in sync.

I came across aptly (https://www.aptly.info/) and it seems to solve this exact problem, without having to mirror full repositories, but only a subset of the packages that you specify, and their dependencies.

I haven't tested it yet, but it looks promising.